# .NET - Get the reference of an object from ListOfObject

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

This is my employee class

```
public class Employee {

  public String Name  {get ;set ;}
  public int ID  {get ;set ;}

}
```

This is my list of employees

```
Public  List<Employee>  lstEmployee ;
lstEmployee=new List<Employee>();

lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { Name ="Abc", Id=1});
lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { Name ="Xyz", Id=2});
lstEmployee.Add(new Employee() { Name ="Pqr", Id=3});
```

So I can query the employee using this

```
Employee emp = lstEmployee. Where(emp=>emp.ID==1);
```

If I print emp.Name and emp.ID , I will get Abc and 1 respectively.

Now I change the values

```
Emp.Name="Test"
```

The value based on the local variable will be updated, but the value of Name in lstEmployee having ID as 1 will be unchanged.

Is there any way to get the reference of the object, so that if we change the property then it will update the list.

Please forgive me if this is a non sense.

I believe I can achieve this by directly applying this on the list , may be like  `lstEmployee. Where(emp=>emp.ID==1).Name="Test"`.

But in my current scenario, there is a function which returns the Emp object from the list and I need to update back. So I think about getting reference . Thanks in advance

Comment: Given the code you showed it *would* update the same reference that is in the list, as currently your local variable is just a copy of the same reference.  Please provide a *complete* program that can replicate the issue that you are having, because as it is the code you've shown won't.

Comment: Are you using Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-object?

Comment: `Employee emp = lstEmployee. Where(emp=>emp.ID==1);' if tries to print emp.Name, then it will return "Abc". After that I update the ` emp.Name ="Test"`. Then if I try to print using lstEmployee. Where(emp=>emp.ID==1).Name, it will print as "Abc" only.

Comment: @Francis there is no SQL. All I have a collection. I need to update the collection

Comment: @VeeKayBee What you are describing is not correct. That is **not** what would happen. Given that your sample code won't even compile, have you tried this?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn this is scenario which I had today and now I re created the same using notepad, sorry for the syntax or type conversion issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The value based on the local variable will be updated, but the value of Name in lstEmployee having ID as 1 will be unchanged.

That's just not true. The only way that would be true is if Employee is defined as a `struct`, rather than a `class`. If you build Employee as a class, the local reference and list reference will both refer to the **same** object, and when you update the local reference, you also update the object in the list.

Additionally, the following code from your question should not compile:

```
Employee emp = lstEmployee. Where(emp=>emp.ID==1);
```

The `.Where()` method returns an `IEnumerable`, not an individual object. You need something more like this:

```
Employee emp = lstEmployee. Where(emp=>emp.ID==1).First();
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. But are you sure that if I update the local variable, then it will update the value in the collection ?. Don't consider the syntax because, I don't have VS with me now. I had a similar problem in my office. Yes I need to use  `First`. Otherwise it returns multiple objects.

Comment: @VeeKayBee Yes, I am sure. The only way it would not happen as I describe is if the Employee type is a struct rather than a class. And building this as a structure is not something I'd recommend.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes you are absolutely correct. Thanks for the information and there is a function which calls every time and reset the collection value to inital value. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Where doesn't return a single object, but a collection. I don't know how you can access the Name property from `Where(emp=>emp.ID==1).Name="Test"`.

I suggest to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`.

```
Employee emp = lstEmployee.FirstOrDefault(emp=>emp.ID==1);
```

Answer (score 1):

List already keeps references.

```
Employee emp = lstEmployee.First(emp=>emp.ID==1);
```

Here emp points the same instance with the pointer inside the list.

So what you said is wrong (the value of Name in lstEmployee having ID as 1 will be unchanged.)
It will be changed.